# XSLT escape apostrophe and quotes

Tags: xslt, escaping, quotes, apostrophe

I have a text like  This is an "example" of 'escaping' in XSLT
I want to replace " with \" and ' with \".
So the output should be 
This is an \"example\" of \'escaping\'.
How can i create a recursive template.
Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0? If so, you can use `replace` to do this easily. If not, then you should upgrade ;)

Comment: If you have to do this in XSLT 1.0, use the recursive str:replace template from exslt.org which handles arbitrary string replacement.

Comment: yeah using XSLT2.0.  I have the templates which escape quotes and apostrophe but i want to create a single template which does the job of both.

Answer (score 0):

In **XSLT 2.0** just add text template

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(&quot;|'')', '\\$1')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
This is an \"example\" of \'escaping\'
```